Nuxt UI won't let me use hexcodes for color
export default defineAppConfig({
  ui: {
    // primary: 'blue', worked when i did this
    // primary: '#3519FA',  trying to do this but won't work
    gray: 'cool',
  }
})


It's clearly explained here that you can use any color name from Tailwind and if you want to add additional colors, use extend.colors['color name'].50: '#EFFDF5' or any other hex code.

In a question like this, it would be better to describe what problem occurs when you try to use the custom colour. Do you get a server error, a client error or does the user just see the default colour?

Has Kissu successfully solved your problem? If so, it might be good for *Kissu to fill it in as an answer, so that MohBJ can mark the question as resolved.
